# Adding Like Functionality to an image

Tags: python, django

New to Django any help will be appreciated. Thank you.
I am trying to add a likes feature to my photos app like Instagram and even show the number of like at the moment I am getting a 'Page not found error'. I sure my logic is not working too

models.py
Photo Model

```
class Photo(models.Model):
img = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
caption = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='Caption here')
date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Likes Model

```
class Like(models.Model):
like = models.IntegerField()
image = models.ForeignKey(Photo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=20)
```

Like Button in a form
PS. I was using I was using class based views here hence the use of 'object'

```
<form action="{ url 'like-photo' object.id }" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="img_id" value="{{ object.id }}">Like</button>
        </form>
```

views.py
I want to be redirected to photo-detail view

```
def LikeView(request, pk):
photo = get_object_or_404(Photo, id=request.POST.get('img_id'))
photo.like.add(request.user)
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('photo-detail', args=[str(pk)]))
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
...
path('like/<int:pk>/', LikeView, name='like-photo'),
```

]

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please include some more context and re-format your code.  It's difficult to determine how your project works.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback. 
What I an trying to accomplish is that user can like a photo and the like is recorded in the database.
The models Photo and Like are as above and I want a User to be able to press a button for a like.
As for the LikeView function in my views.py you can ignore it completely and show me another way of doing it. 
As for the User, I am using Django's inbuilt User model.
I hope this helps, thank you